# how to bind fileurls to NavigationLink list SwiftUI

Tags: ios, list, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to bind fileurls array to NavigationLink list I have an error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[URL]>' to expected argument
> type 'Range'

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var fileUrls:[URL] = []
    
    func listDir(dir: String) -> [URL] {
       // list file from directory 
    }
   
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    List{
                        ForEach($fileUrls) { object in
                            NavigationLink(destination: PDFKitView(url: self.fileUrl1), isActive: $viewLocalPDF) {
                                Button("Swift Style"){
                                    self.viewLocalPDF = true
                                }.padding(.bottom, 20)
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Bookshelv ", displayMode: .inline).onAppear {
                    fileUrls = listDir(dir: "pdfs")
                }
                
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `$` you're referring to the `Binding` of `fileUrls`. You don't need the Binding for the `ForEach`, just the value.

Because URL doesn't conform to `Identifiable`, you'll also need to tell it how to identify each item. For this, you can just use `\.self`:

```
ForEach(fileUrls, id: \.self) { object in
```